# Load Prefab through PlayerPrefers at new scene

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

In the main menu of my game there is a section for the player to choose the skin of your character and enter the game.

I'm struggling to save the "Controller Animator" & "Transform" in PlayerPrefers which was selected by the user and instantiates it in the next scene "Game" at x-0, Y-0, z-0.

All skins already has its "Controller" & "Transform" attached to the inspector (see pic attached).

Only I can not instantiate them in the next "Game" scene.

[image: Menu skin CHOICE]

[image: Game SCENE]

Below my scrip to select the skin and enter the "Game".

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Choice : MonoBehaviour {

    public RuntimeAnimatorController anim;
    public Transform Bee;
    string skinChoice = "skin";

    public void ChangeAnimator() {

        Animator animator = Bee.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        animator.runtimeAnimatorController = anim;
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Game");
    }
}
```

Comment: using playerprefs is very easy: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Answer (score -1):

You can set the name of the prefab as static string and refer to it at the beginning of the next game scene:

```
public static string skinchoice = "skin";
```

And a Creator class:

```
public class Creator : MonoBehaviour { 
    void Start(){
        if (Choice.skinchoice == "skin1") Instantiate(Bee1);
        else if (Choice.skinchoice == "skin2") Instantiate(Bee2);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: varu, generally never use "static" in Unity.  certainly beginners should never do so; it's almost impossible to understand what it means in an ECS setting. (Also it's totally irrelevant to this question: just use PlayerPrefs.)

Comment: I didn't know playerprefs, but I understand they're used for different game sessions, but it probably is a better idea. Anyway, why not using statics in Unity?